# Can you find the logic/syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have been going line by line through my code trying to find an error, however i am yet to succeed.

Shown below are snippets of my input and update files.

**modifyform.php**

```
                    <li id="li_1" >
        <label class="description" for="servername">Server Name </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_1" name="Servername" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo $person['servername']; ?>"/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_1"><small>Enter your server name here NOT your server address.</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="Serveraddress">Server Address </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_2" name="Serveraddress" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo $person['serveraddress']; ?>"/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_2"><small>This will the DNS name of your server</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_3" >
        <label class="description" for="Portnumber">PortNumber </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_3" name="Portnumber" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo $person['portnumber']; ?>"/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_3"><small>This will be the port your server is using.</small></p> 

        <label class="description" for="Status">Server Status </label>
               <div>
            <input id="element_4" name="Status" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo $person['status']; ?>"/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_4"><small> Display your Server Status</small></p> 

        </li>       <li id="li_4" >
        <label class="description" for="Description">Server Description </label>
        <div>
            <textarea id="element_5" name="Description" class="element textarea medium" value ="<?php echo $person['description']; ?>"></textarea> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_5"><small>Enter server description/rules here.</small></p> 
        </li>

                    <li class="buttons">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />

                <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Modify" />
        </li>
            </ul>
        </form> 
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>-
</html>
```

**modifyame.php**

```
<?php


mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die (mysql_error());
#echo "Connected to MYSQL ";
mysql_select_db("starforg_search") or die (mysql_error());
#echo "Connected to Data Base";
/*$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE userId='{$user_id}'";
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die (mysql_error());*/

    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $q = "SELECT * FROM addserverame WHERE ID = $_GET[id] AND userId='{$user_id}'";
    $result = mysql_query ($q);
    $person = mysql_fetch_array ($result);
    }

    ?>



<?

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $u = "UPDATE addserverame SET `servername`='$_POST[Servername]', `serveraddress`='$_POST[Serveraddress]', `portnumber`='$_POST[Portnumber]', `status`='$_POST[Status]', `description`='$_POST[Description]', WHERE ID = $_POST[id] AND userId='{$user_id}'";
    mysql_query($u) or die (mysql_error());
    echo "Server Info Has Been Modified";
}
?>
```

**The Problem area** 
Update and echoing the servername,serveraddress and portnumber fields are fine however echoing/updating description and status fields are not working.

I have looked over the table names numerous times and i am admit they are correct.

This brings me to believe syntax errors may be the culprit.

Thanks for your time

Ben

Comment: echo $u and find the error

Comment: Debug your own code! This is not a question.

Comment: Also, escape your `$_POST` vars, you don't want a nasty injection.

Comment: @ Cumbo yes reading on how to fix that was the next thing on to-do list.

Comment: @Sverri M, If you don't want to help why are you here......

Comment: learn to fish, don't expect fish to be given to you.

Comment: @bennyboy I love answering questions, but this is just a debug request. If this was a question you would have isolated the problem and asked a pointed question about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a syntax error on your `UPDATE` statement. You have extra `,` before the `WHERE` clause that should be removed.

```
UPDATE  addserverame 
SET  `servername`='$_POST[Servername]', 
     `serveraddress`='$_POST[Serveraddress]', 
     `portnumber`='$_POST[Portnumber]', 
     `status`='$_POST[Status]', 
     `description`='$_POST[Description]', -- <<=== REMOVE extra comma HERE
WHERE ID = $_POST[id] AND 
      userId='{$user_id}'
```

Make it a habit to align codes so syntax error mistakes can be easily spotted.

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Great Thanks, its always great to have a second pair of eyes. I will Give you correct answer when the timer runs out.

Comment: you're welcome `:D` but hey, please also read about `sql injection`..

Comment: yer i am going to fix that after i fixed this, thanks again